# To send Sms directly to fixed user

Tags: android, sms

I have tried the code to send the sms to fixed user But According to my functionality I want to send the sms which depends on flag.When flag is true then to send the sms directly.Now It is calling the Intent and goes to the sms screen and when there we click on send button then it will send the sms.But I dont want to come on this screen,I want to send sms directly to fixed user

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"
                + phoneNumber)));
```

And

```
String x="Hello World";
String y="You Rock!!!";
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", x); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", y); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use [SMSManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) class to send a message directly. 
Use [SmsManager.sentextMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) api in the above class

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm. sendTextMessage(phoneNumber,null,x,null,null);
```

and add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: can you explain it little bit more please

Comment: what do you want to know? Instead of doing startActivity, you will have to use above code. And add permission

Comment: Means in above code which i have posted in that instead of startActivity your code Correct ?

Comment: No, for sending MMS you will have to use default messaging app

Answer (score 2):

Try using the code given below :

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
```

*Note:*

Use ***android.telephony.SmsManager*** class (***android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager*** is deprecated)